# how to install nordvpn

Tags: nordvpn

I tried to install nordvpn from the site . It would appear to have worked because the app is amonst the apps on my computer . When i click on it nothing happens though . I looked on the internet and followed the advice using sudo apt-get but that didnt work either . I don't know where to go from here .
Easy advice please ?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.